# How to find out what package contains some Perl module

Tags: package-management, deb, perl, cpan

I need to install some CPAN module on my Ubuntu computer. I want to install it from deb package so I need to find out what package contains that module.

Sometimes the solution for this task is pretty simple. For example if I need to install [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find::Rule) I just convert the name to lowercase, change `::` to `-` and add `lib` to the beginning and `-perl` to the end. The result is the package name `libfile-find-rule-perl`:

```
$ apt-cache search libfile-find-rule-perl
libfile-find-rule-perl - module to search for files based on rules
```

But in other cases this is not working. I want to find deb package that contains [Debian::AptContents](https://metacpan.org/module/Debian::AptContents). But `apt-cache search libdebian-aptcontents-perl` finds nothing.

Well, in the case of [Debian::AptContents](https://metacpan.org/module/Debian::AptContents) I know that it is in the package `dh-make-perl`, but I want to know how to find what deb package contains the module I need.

Comment: Do you want to do this only using the command line?

Comment: Well, yes, I prefer to solve this problem with the comand line tools. But I'm also interested if there is some web site with this information. I will not use any solution with windows based apps (I don't have X server on my machine), but I will appresiate any kind of solution =)

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu there is a package searching utility called `apt-file`. You can pass file name to it and it will show you the package containing that file. It search not only the packages that are installed on your system, but also the package that are available for installation.

To find out the deb package that contains [Debian::AptContents](https://metacpan.org/module/Debian%3a%3aAptContents) you should run:

```
$ apt-file search Debian/AptContents.pm
dh-make-perl: /usr/share/perl5/Debian/AptContents.pm
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use search at packages.ubuntu.com
E.g.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=contents&keywords=find%2Frule.pm
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=aptcontents.pm&searchon=contents

Answer (score 1):

From a console `whereis PACKAGE_OR_COMMON_FILE`: it will print any occurrence of a system file.
If you have `aptitude` use: `aptitude search PACKAGE_NAME`. If it's present, execute `aptitude`, find it with the `search` option and press `ENTER` to see more information.
If you need info on the module use `cpan -D module`.

Comment: Lorenzo, Thank you for the `cpan -D` command!

Comment: Feel free to ask other things if you need more help! ;)